# Java how to write : test extends a generic test

Tags: java, generics, testing

I am writing 3 different class tests: `HardSudoku`, `VeryHardSudoku` and `Sudoku`.

The `HardSudoku` and `VeryHardSudoku` classes extend the `Sudoku` class.

So I would have liked to write these three tests in such a way as to respect the DRY principle, so, for that, I think that the best solution is to use genericity within the tests.

Here is how I wanted to proceed:

### Tests :

#### `SudokuTest`

```java
class SudokuTest<T extends Sudoku> {

    @Test
    void test_solve_dontThrowError() {
        T sudoku = new T();
        assertAll(() -> sudoku.solve());
    }

    @Test
    void test_solve_returnValidSolution() {
        T sudoku = new T();
        sudoku.solve();
        assertTrue(SolutionChecker.isValid(sudoku.getGridSolution()));
    }
}
```

#### `HardSudokuTest`

```java
public class HardSudokuTest extends SudokuTest<HardSudoku> {
    
}
```

#### `VeryHardSudokuTest`

```java
public class VeryHardSudokuTest extends SudokuTest<VeryHardSudoku> {
    
}
```

### Question

The line in the `SudokuClass` test class:

```java
T sudoku = new T();
```

Is not valid, so I wanted to ask you how to write these 3 tests in a way that respects the DRY principle? Is it possible to use genericity?

Comment: Well, first of all what's the differences between Sudoku, HardSudoku and VeryHardSudoku? Why did you decide to use inheritance?

Comment: @SergeiTonoian The difference between these three classes is not very big, for example in the `HardSudoku` class we only have one constructor which contains `super(Data.HARD_SUDOKU);`.
Creating these three classes is a requirement of my teacher for this project, he uses them to get a grade per class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, a better solution would be to scrap the generics completely and approach the problem as follows.

Refactor the `SudokuTest` class as follows:

```java
abstract class SudokuTestHelper {
    private Supplier<Sudoku> supplier;
    private Sudoku sudoku;
      
    SudokuTestHelper(Supplier<Sudoku> supplier) {
      this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
      this.sudoku = supplier.get();
    }

    @Test
    void test_solve_dontThrowError() {
        assertAll(() -> sudoku.solve());
    }

    @Test
    void test_solve_returnValidSolution() {
        sudoku.solve();
        assertTrue(SolutionChecker.isValid(sudoku.getGridSolution()));
    }
}
```

You can now test different implementations of the generic Sudoku interface by creating new test classes looking like the following:

```java
class HardSudokuTest extends SudokuTestHelper {
  HardSudokuTest() {
    super(HardSudoku::new);
  }
}
```

Comment: *NOTE:* Replace `@BeforeEach` with `@Before` if using JUnit 4.

Answer (score 2):

What do you think of this idea ? (NOT TESTED)

```
class SudokuTest<T extends Sudoku> {
    private T sudoku; // property
    
    public SudokuTest(T t) {
        sudoku = t;
    }

    @Test
    void test_solve_dontThrowError() {
        assertAll(() -> sudoku.solve());
    }

    @Test
    void test_solve_returnValidSolution() {
        sudoku.solve();
        assertTrue(SolutionChecker.isValid(sudoku.getGridSolution()));
    }
}
```

With...

```
public class HardSudokuTest extends SudokuTest<HardSudoku> {
    public HardSudokuTest() {
       super(new HardSudoku())
   }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that with this approach you're re-using the same `sudoku` instance over all methods rather than creating a new one for each method, as opposed to your original proposed code snippets.

Comment: @DomenicoSibilio Indeed, I have just noticed it. Do you have a suggestion to correct this problem?

Comment: I'll add another answer with my suggested approach ;)

Comment: You are right @DomenicoSibilio. At first sight, I might pass as many T params as I need to the generic test, so that each testing method will have its own one. But let's see the answer of Domenico.